# Unable to scroll selenium driver to pull certain number of posts

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, reddit

*I am new to selenium and trying to pull certain number of posts(from a subreddit) but unable to scroll the webpage. I tried all other stack overflow posts, but didn't work for me.**

`# set the url for scraping. here im scraping fitness subreddit. url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/'`

````
# inst object that can start and stop the browser
ser = Service('chromedriver/chromedriver')

# inst object that controls the browser/driver 
# [drive the chromedriver]
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)

# send a request to get url
driver.get(url)

# scroll to bottom of page to load extra posts
# driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
driver.execute_script("""window.scrollBy({ 
top: document.body.scrollHeight, // negative value acceptable
left: 0, 
behavior: 'smooth' 
});""")


# wait a few seconds for the full page to load
sleep(100) # seconds

# grab the html of the url loaded in driver 
html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')```

Above code bring my output for post's title as follows:

```# pull title
title = [span.text for span in soup.find_all('h3',{'class':"_eYtD2XCVieq6emjKBH3m"})]
len(title)```

Output:
<<<18
````

Answer (score 0):

here is an alternative method you can use:

```
webpage=driver.find_element_by_xpath("*")
for i in range(100):
    webpage.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
```

You can adjust how much it scrolls with the value of the range.